# Access JSF ViewScoped managed bean from Servlet

Tags: jsf, servlets

How may I access a JSF ViewScoped managed bean from a Servlet?

(Assume that the managed bean in question has already been created, and still not been destroyed)

Comment: If you need to access the bean outside its scope that suggests it has not been scoped appropriately.

Comment: As far as the corresponding page is live the ViewScoped bean is live, then why can't I call a Servlet from that page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View-scoped variables are stored in the [view map](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#getViewMap%28%29) on the component tree. To access this data outside the view context you would have to [create a JSF context](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContextFactory.html#getFacesContext%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object,%20javax.faces.lifecycle.Lifecycle%29) and [restore the view](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/StateManager.html#restoreView%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for the request. This involves rewriting much of the functionality provided by the [JSF container](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.html).

JSF 2 provides mechanisms for interacting with server-side state without a page refresh: [AJAX tags](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu-0610/index.html) and the [JSF JavaScript API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/js-api/index.html). I would look at utilizing those if possible.

Alternatively, place the data into a scope that is easily accessible via servlets (the session.)

*Since the view state is generally held in the session, it is likely technically possible to access the view state from here. But this would involve implementation-specific hacks that may not survive an upgrade of the underlying framework. I wouldn't even look at this as a solution.*